# unable to upload sketch

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, arduino-uno

Unable to upload a simple code to Arduino Board since many days. I am using Arduino UNO with all updated drivers. My OS is Windows 7. Trying to do blink on and off. Details in a photo below.[image]

Not Sure Which Board I have. I think it's Arduino UNO but It says Arduino R1. Can you Please tell? Picture below. [image]

Comment: Is there sth. connected to the rx tx ports on your arduino? Is the right port and board selected in arduino IDE?

Comment: Is your IDE configured to use 9600bps, 8 bits, no parity and 1 stop bit?

Comment: My Driver settings : http://i.imgur.com/cGgKc2d.jpg

Comment: @Lukasstr Added photo of the Board in question body. Not sure which one is it, but I think it is Arduino UNO.

Comment: can't even find this arduino anywhere... looks really antique - look in the chematics... perhaps your jumpers are wrong/not existent, perhaps the atmega is the wrong model/not working

Comment: http://arduino.stackexchange.com or http://superuser.com are better places for this question

Answer (score 1):

So I was selecting the wrong Board. Also had to update my Drivers. My Board was Arduino Duemilanove